# is there a documented limit to the number of slaves you can have in redis?

Tags: replication, redis

I'm trying to find any documentation about the maximum number of slaves you can set up in a redis  master / slave configuration.  We can potentially have 200 slaves. 
If there is a limit, I might switch gears and consider messaging solution with REDIS instead of replication.

So far I haven't been able to find anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As a side note, I did find out that you can have slaves connected to slaves in Redis.